# Real Time Page Template Preview in WP Admin

Tags: templates

I'm a little afraid to ask this question on Stack Exchange as it could be "off topic".

I use many different page templates for a marketing sites 'landing pages', as these templates are re-used I would like to add a feature which would allow Editors / Admin to preview a page before applying the template, updating page and previewing the page itself.

Basically, I am looking to create a 'real-time' preview function for page templates, so users can quickly browse for a template they are looking for.

I apologise for the format of the question but Google provides no insight...